# How to use an if loop in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

Question:  Create a new column with a 1 if the country's % Renewable value is at or above the median for all countries in the top 15, and a 0 if the country's % Renewable value is below the median.

My Solution:

```
medi = Top15['% Renewable'].median()

if Top15['% Renewable'] >= medi:

    Top15['new col'] = 1

else:

    Top15['new col'] = 0

Top15
```

Error:  The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Help: Can someone please tell me why this error is coming?[Click on this link to see the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osOK9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
medi = Top15['% Renewable'].median()
Top15['new col'] = Top15['% Renewable'].apply(lambda x:1 if x>medi else 0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But can you please explain what's wrong with my approach.? What's the fundamental error?

Comment: `if Top15['% Renewable'] >= medi:`
This line is wrong as you are passing a column series to check instead of 1 value.
To use your own method you will have a make a loop that fetches value one by one and the based on consition set the value using `Top15["new col"].iloc[position]=1/0`

Answer (score 0):

Apply
    df['new column name'] = df['column name'].apply(lambda x: 'value if condition is met' if x condition else 'value if condition is not met')

Answer (score 0):

```
medi = Top15['% Renewable'].median()
Top15['new col'] = Top15['% Renewable'].transform(lambda value: 1 if value>=medi else 0)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.